# Cumsum entire table and reset at zero

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have following data frame.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [0,1,1,1,0,1],'two' : [0,0,1,0,1,1]})

d

   one  two
0    0    0
1    1    0
2    1    1
3    1    0
4    0    1
5    1    1
```

I want cumulative sum which resets at zero

**desired output should be**

```
pd.DataFrame({'one' : [0,1,2,3,0,1],'two' : [0,0,1,0,1,2]})

   one  two
0    0    0
1    1    0
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    0    1
5    1    2
```

i have tried using group by but it does not work for entire table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df2 =  df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby((~x.astype(bool)).cumsum()).cumsum())
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   one  two
0    0    0
1    1    0
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    0    1
5    1    2
```

Answer (score 3):

## `pandas`

```
def cum_reset_pd(df):
    csum = df.cumsum()
    return (csum - csum.where(df == 0).ffill()).astype(d.dtypes)

cum_reset_pd(d)

   one  two
0    0    0
1    1    0
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    0    1
5    1    2
```

## `numpy`

```
def cum_reset_np(df):
    v = df.values
    z = np.zeros_like(v)
    j, i = np.where(v.T)
    r = np.arange(1, i.size + 1)
    p = np.where(
        np.append(False, (np.diff(i) != 1) | (np.diff(j) != 0))
    )[0]
    b = np.append(0, np.append(p, r.size))
    z[i, j] = r - b[:-1].repeat(np.diff(b))
    return pd.DataFrame(z, df.index, df.columns)

cum_reset_np(d)

   one  two
0    0    0
1    1    0
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    0    1
5    1    2
```

---

***Why go through this trouble?***
*because it's quicker!*

[image]

Comment: I think df[5,'one'] should equal 1 and not 4.

Comment: Its worth the trouble! People should take time to understand rather than complain about readability :)

Comment: @Divakar Any good online course on NumPy?   Of course reading that docs is a great place to start.

Comment: @ScottBoston Hmm, well I came from MATLAB background, so I started with [NumPy for MATLAB](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) and of course the docs too. I guess it would depend on the background one is comfortable with it mixed with constant doc references.

Answer (score 1):

This one is without using Pandas, but using NumPy and list comprehensions:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'one': [0,1,1,1,0,1], 'two': [0,0,1,0,1,1]}

out = {}
for key in d.keys():
    l = d[key]
    indices = np.argwhere(np.array(l)==0).flatten()
    indices = np.append(indices, len(l))
    out[key] = np.concatenate([np.cumsum(l[indices[n-1]:indices[n]]) \
                   for n in range(1, indices.shape[0])]).ravel()
print(out)
```

First, I find all occurences of `0` (positions to split the lists), then I calculate `cumsum` of the resulting sublists and insert them into a new `dict`.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
d = {'one' : [0,1,1,1,0,1],'two' : [0,0,1,0,1,1]}
one = d['one']
two = d['two']
i = 0
new_one = []
for item in one:
    if item == 0:
        i = 0
    else:
        i += item
    new_one.append(i)

j = 0
new_two = []
for item in two:
    if item == 0:
        j = 0
    else:
        j += item
    new_two.append(j)

d['one'], d['two'] = new_one, new_two
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```